# a.getTime is not a function - Google Charts

Tags: javascript, json

Boa noite

Gostaria de saber se alguém já pegou esse erro ao criar os gráficos pelo Google Charts

a.getTime is not a function

Retorno do Json

{"cols":[{"label":"Nome","type":"string"},{"label":"Data","type":"date"},{"label":"Quantidade","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Leonardo"},{"v":"2019-05-02"},{"v":"229"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Leonardo"}

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="teste" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
    
    <script>

      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: "control/getTeste.php",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
            }).responseText;

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        
        

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('teste'));

        chart.draw(data, null);
      }
    </script>
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que como você declarou o tipo de dado `date` no seu JSON, o código por traz do Google Charts esteja tentando chamar um método existente na classe `Date` na sua data, mas sua data é uma `string`, não um `Date`, por isso o erro.

Se você transformar a sua `string` de data em um objeto `Date` manualmente, o erro parece não ocorrer:

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "control/getTeste.php",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
}).responseText;

jsonData.rows.forEach(r => r.c[1].v = new Date(r.c[1].v));
```

Outra alternativa seria declarar a data como tipo `string`.

Comment: Ajuste como string e deu certo @user140828